# better gradle expression to do fileTrees.add() for all subprojects

Tags: android, gradle

To configure [SpotBugs](https://github.com/spotbugs) to Android `build.gradle` file, below expression seems very ineffective. 
I'm not good at groovy script, but there could be a better way to do.

```
tasks.withType(com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask) {
    classes = fileTree("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes")
            .plus(fileTree("${rootProject.rootDir}/../subproject-one/app/build/intermediates/classes"))
            .plus(fileTree("${rootProject.rootDir}/../subproject-two/app/build/intermediates/classes"))
            .plus(fileTree("${rootProject.rootDir}/../subproject-three/app/build/intermediates/classes"))
}
```

Actually, all subprojects `fileTree` targets are iterated ones of `${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes`.

The lefthand `classes` are `org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection` type refer to the [SpotBugs gradle plugin source code](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/blob/7f895ddc8cf6c35c57e744131d4a2be03cd80503/src/main/java/com/github/spotbugs/SpotBugsTask.java#L59)

My trial is as below;

```
    // not working
    classes = rootProject.subprojects.collect({
        proj -> fileTree("${proj.buildDir}/intermediates/classes") })
                        .stream().asType(org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection.class)
```

And it gives below error;

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:spotbugsMain'.
>
> > No signature of method: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.getBuildDependencies() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

I knew why it gives such an error, but I could not imagine how to fix it properly.
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SpotBugsTask has a setClasses(FileCollection) method you could do

```
tasks.withType(com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask) {
   List<File> dirs = subprojects.collect { it.file("${it.buildDir}/intermediates/classes") } 
   classes = files(dirs) 
}
```

See groovy docs for [iterating on a list](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_iterating_on_a_list)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, it gives `ERROR: Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection()` error.